# MySQL Comparing 'LEFT JOIN IS NULL' vs 'GROUP BY'

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, isnull

I used 'LEFT JOIN IS NULL' for grouping purposes very often and I thought that this was the best way to group records by one field and find the record with max value by another field within each group.

For isntance,

```
SELECT i.* FROM instance i  
LEFT JOIN instance itemp on itemp.client = i.client AND itemp.updated_at > i.updated_at 
WHERE itemp.id IS NULL
```

gives the the freshest records for each client.

But this query turned out to be very slow (~200 sec) for small DB

- Total number of 'instance' records: 27000
- 90% of them (24000) belongs to one client
- 10% of them evenly distributed through 5 other clients
- Values of the field 'updated_at' are distributed very evenly
- There are indexes (client, updated_at) and (client)

At the same time the query with grouping

```
SELECT inst.* FROM instance inst,
(
    SELECT i.client AS cl, MAX(i.updated_at) AS up 
    FROM instance i     
    GROUP BY i.client
) AS max_values
WHERE 
inst.client = max_values.cl AND inst.updated_at = max_values.up
```

takes just 63 ms.

Why the first query is so slow in comparison with the second?

The EXPLAIN for first query

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "i" "ALL"   \N  \N  \N  \N  "27247" "100.00"    ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "itemp" "ref"   "updated_at,client,client_updated_at"   "client_updated_at" "183"   "schibsted_auth.i.client"   "908"   "100.00"    "Using where; Using index; Not exists"
```

The EXPLAIN for second query

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"
"1" "PRIMARY"   "<derived2>"    "ALL"   \N  \N  \N  \N  "8" "100.00"    ""
"1" "PRIMARY"   "inst"  "ref"   "updated_at,client,client_updated_at"   "updated_at"    "8" "max_values.up" "1" "100.00"    "Using where"
"2" "DERIVED"   "i" "range" \N  "client_updated_at" "183"   \N  "31"    "100.00"    "Using index for group-by"
```

Comment: Take a look at the execution plan.

Comment: do **not** use a JOIN algorithm for anything else than crossing resulsets. The 2nd subquery based SQL is the proper approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of both queries and look over the input (this may come in handy: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/). Most likely, the slowness is related to the updated_at join condition.

Your first table is doing a self join with `itemp.client = i.client AND itemp.updated_at > i.updated_at`.

The later is effectively an inner join with `inst.client = max_values.cl AND inst.updated_at = max_values.up`, which in turn will be faster by virtue of the equality reference on updated_at . This is especially relevant since your data are skewed and one of your client has 24000 records associated with it. The application is very probably comparing which of the 24000 itemp.updated_at values are greater than which of the 24000 i.updated_at values. In your second query, it doesn't have to do that expensive, combinatorical join. It just matches on equality and moves on.

Again, I'm not 100% clear that that is what is happening. But I bet if you place EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of both queries, that's what you're gonna see. It would be especially useful to see EXPLAIN EXTENDED for that one client with 24000 observations. Add a where clause for that client and execute both statements with EXPLAIN... I bet it will stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Probably you are right , the problem is in combinatorical join within 24000 records. If I exclude this big client from first query ( WHERE ... AND i.client <> 'bad_client'), then it works fast. If I filter only this client ( WHERE ... AND i.client = 'bad_client'), then it becomes very slow. I added the EXPLAIN results for both queries